# select faz aparecer campos de input e de select

Tags: javascript, html, select, formulário

Pessoal preciso que que o campo de imput aparece e o campo select com os estado quando o usuário seleciona sua área te atuação caso ele selecione Acadêmico, Outros ou Não sou da Areá da Saúde não apareça isso foi que que consegui ate agora alguém pode me ajudar

```
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i></span>

                    <select id="TipoDocumento" name="TipoDocumento" class="form-control" required>
                        <option data-tipo=""></option>
                        <option data-tipo="Biomédico">Biomédico</option>
                        <option data-tipo="Dentista">Dentista</option>
                        <option data-tipo="Médico">Médico</option>
                        <option data-tipo="Farmacêutico">Farmacêutico</option>
                        <option data-tipo="Enfermeiro">Enfermeiro</option>
                        <option data-tipo="Acadêmico">Acadêmico</option>
                        <option data-tipo="Outros">Outros</option>
                        <option data-tipo="nao">Não sou da Areá da Saúde</option>
                        </select>
                        <span id="InputsDocumento">
                         <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="CRO" id="Biomédico" placeholder="Digite seu CRO" disabled>
                         <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="CRO" id="Dentista" placeholder="Digite seu CRO" disabled>
                         <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="CRO" id="Médico" placeholder="Digite seu CRO" disabled>
                         <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="CRO" id="Farmacêutico" placeholder="Digite seu CRO" disabled>
                         <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="CRO" id="Enfermeiro" placeholder="Digite seu CRO" disabled>
                         <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="Acadêmico" id="Acadêmico" placeholder="Digite seu RG" disabled>
                         <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="outros" id="Outros" placeholder="Digite seu CRO" disabled>
                         <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="CRO" id="Não sou da Areá da Saúde" placeholder="CPF" disabled>
                        </span>
                        <select name="estado" class="form-control" id="TipoDocumento" required>
                            <option value="AC">Acre</option>
                            <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
                            <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
                            <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
                            <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
                            <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
                            <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
                            <option value="GO.">Goiás</option>
                            <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
                            <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
                            <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                            <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
                            <option value="PA">Pará</option>
                            <option value="PB.">Paraíba</option>
                            <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
                            <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
                            <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
                            <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                            <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                            <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                            <option value="RO.">Rondônia</option>
                            <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
                            <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
                            <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                            <option value="SE.">Sergipe</option>
                            <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
                            <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
                        </select>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

aqui o js

```
 //desabilita e esconde todos os inputs do campo area de atuação
      $('#TipoDocumento').change(function(e) {
         let opcaoSelecionada = this.querySelector('option:checked');
  
  //desabilita e esconde todos os inputs
        let inputs = $('#InputsDocumento input');
         inputs.attr('type', 'hidden');
         inputs.attr('disabled', '');
  
  //habilita e mostra o input relevante
        let inputEscolhido = inputs.filter('#'+ opcaoSelecionada.dataset.tipo);
         inputEscolhido.attr('type', 'text');
         if (opcaoSelecionada.dataset.tipo !== 'placeholder')
         inputEscolhido.removeAttr('disabled');
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente altere o id do select "estado", estava o mesmo do tipo:

```
<select name="estado" class="form-control" id="estado" required>
```

No exemplo que fiz coloquei estado

Depois no Js, verifica o valor e se for um dos três, esconde o select, caso não, mostra.
Este código vai dentro da função onchange que fez.

```
//mostra ou não o estado
      switch($('#TipoDocumento').val()) {
        case "Acadêmico":
        case "Outros":
        case "Não sou da Areá da Saúde":          
                $("#estado").hide();
            break;
        default:
            $("#estado").show();
          break;
      }
```

Seu Js completo fica assim:

```
//desabilita e esconde todos os inputs do campo area de atuação
  $('#TipoDocumento').change(function(e) {
         let opcaoSelecionada = this.querySelector('option:checked');
  
  //desabilita e esconde todos os inputs
        let inputs = $('#InputsDocumento input');
         inputs.attr('type', 'hidden');
         inputs.attr('disabled', '');
  
  //habilita e mostra o input relevante
        let inputEscolhido = inputs.filter('#'+ opcaoSelecionada.dataset.tipo);
         inputEscolhido.attr('type', 'text');
         if (opcaoSelecionada.dataset.tipo !== 'placeholder')
         inputEscolhido.removeAttr('disabled');
         
         
      //mostra/nãom mostra o estado
      switch($('#TipoDocumento').val()) {
        case "Acadêmico":
        case "Outros":
        case "Não sou da Areá da Saúde":          
                $("#estado").hide();
            break;
        default:
            $("#estado").show();
          break;
      }
   });
```

Fiddle do código rodando: https://jsfiddle.net/woLfvs72/3/